# Is an API key worthless over http since requested parameters can be sniffed?

Tags: web-services, security, http, api-key

Is an API key worthless over http since requested parameters can be sniffed?
Are they only reliable over https?
Even then, aren't you relying on the client to be careful with their key?

Comment: The same points hold true for passwords. Are passwords worthless?

Comment: Good point about that when it's over https, but what about http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is an API key worthless over http since requested parameters can be sniffed?

No, because sniffing can only be performed if you are on the same LAN with the sysadmins being clueless about IT security, or if you can otherwise capture the transmitted traffic (which is typically pretty hard). Also, there exist technologies like IPSec that provide authenticity and privacy on the network layer.

So using plaintext authentication does not provide *zero* additional security.

> Are they only reliable over https?

This depends on your definition of "reliable". See above. In any case, using transport security prevents attackers from reading your communication. If SSL is enforced, man-in-the-middle attacks are prevented as well.

> Even then, aren't you relying on the client to be careful with their key?

Of course you do, you *always* have to trust your authorized users. This has nothing to do with API keys or passwords or anything.

Comment: Plenty of MITM attacks are possible without being on the same network segment. Hijacked DNS, for instance, is a common way to achieve this. (e.g. [DNSChanger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSChanger) ). There are many others.

Comment: @Billy: Distributing a full-blown trojan to then forge DNS responses is what I'd call "hard". It's even harder if you have a specific target. Not impossible, of course, but that wasn't my point.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the API key is being used.

If you assign an API key to a developer, and the developer distributes the API key as part of an mobile app, or uses the API key to make AJAX calls from a web page - then the API key is pointless. Anybody can sniff the key, and it does not need any sophisticated man in the middle attack.

But if the developer uses the API key from server side code, and your API works over https, then this is a fairly secure technique.

In short, the security lies in trusting the developer to keep the API key secret. Just like you'd expect users to keep their passwords secret.